# Color[] col= {Color.RED,Color.BLUE}; what does it means in java?

Tags: java

I'm reading java swing and i'm having problem in understanding it. Is `Color` a `class`?

```
Color[] col= {Color.RED,Color.BLUE};
```

What does it means in java?

Comment: yes it is a Class

Comment: What specifically are you asking about? The `[]` notation, the initialization of values between `{` and `}`, the `Color.RED` or `Color.BLUE` values?

Comment: you can learn more about arrays here : http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays#t=201610141757039742981

Comment: In standard Java (Java SE) exist `java.awt.Color` class and when you scroll your code up you will most likely see `import java.awt.Color;` or `import java.awt.*;`. Here is its source code: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/awt/Color.java

Comment: did you understand?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ...

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv because of what?

Answer (score 1):

> Is Color a class?

Yes.

Color is a class that has many static members for the different colors, as well as a constructor for a specific color (RGB values).

What this means

```
Color[] col= new Color[]{Color.RED,Color.BLUE};
```

is an array of Colors called col which has the values of red and blue. Notice I've changed it from `Color[] col= {Color.RED,Color.BLUE};` to `Color[] col = new Color[]{Color.RED,Color.BLUE};` because you have to actually create the color array (hence the `new` keyword).

Answer (score 0):

[Color is a Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) and that line of code is **declaring AND initializing** an array of colors with the name **col** and initializing it with the constants

Color.RED and Color.BLUE

Answer (score 0):

Color is a class, that has several constants, for instance RED and BLUE.
These two instances of the class Color are put into an array.
So you have something like a "list" with two colors.